# Feedback on Data Science LSTM Project

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, data-science

I realize that this is slightly outside the realm of what sort of questions are normally asked here, so please forgive that. I have been tasked with an open ended technical screening for a job as a data scientist. This is my first job that has asked for something like this, so I want to make sure that I am submitting really good work. I was given a dataset and asked to identify the problem and how to use machine learning to solve it, give stats on the target feature, pre-process the data data, model the data, and interpret the results.

I am looking for feedback about if I am missing anything huge in my results. High level feedback is fine. Hopefully some of you are data scientists and have either had to complete a technical screening like this or have had to review one and can offer some valuable feedback to an up-and-coming data scientist.

Thank you!

[Github Link to Project](https://github.com/datascientistphl/machine-learning/blob/master/LSTM.ipynb)

Comment: I would have explain how other team have taken the problem into account, a description of the state of the art with link reference, and why you choosed this method in comparison to others (because there is other method)

Comment: there was a chalenge with mars express orbiter to do exactly what you have been asked for : predict the consumption knowing some parameters : https://kelvins.esa.int/mars-express-power-challenge/ different team worked on it and the winner doesnt used a LSTM. (dont mean that it is right to not use it) https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2018-2561

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look on the

> Mars Express Power Challenge Get the data, model and predict the
>   thermal power consumption

here https://kelvins.esa.int/mars-express-power-challenge/

The chalenge was to get the data and predict future consumption of the orbiter to plan how to save energy (when in the solar field there is a risk of over heating, and in the solar night a risk from being to cold)

The teams used different approach LSTM is probably the one I would choose. But the winning team conducted a very detailed explanation on the "Feature Engineering and Selection".The point is what is important is not the tool used but the correct choice of feature extraction and selection.
https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/pdf/10.2514/6.2018-2561

I read both the winning paper and your work. Really I prefer your way. 
As you see if you read the paper, your methodology is quite comparable, but they put the feature extraction study at the center of the research.

You may secure your work by providing more evidences that you picked the right method  for the FE. For exemple you could provide 2 method of FE and compare the result given the method, or, you explain you chosen one knowing the current state of the art about this particular paper which prove blablabla...

You could add the comparative result of ARIMA VAR VARMA and yours to illustrate the "outperform" and reference on papers of the state of the art for the past 3 years on the field, and other references on recent publication on LSTM for energy consumption prediction.

Your document end abruptly one would wait for a decorative conclusion as we are used to find in a regular paper.

That it.

(please dont take account of my only opinion as I don't feel myself data-scientist :) I will be very proud of myself the day I would be abble to produce what you done ;) thanks for sharing it was nice to read it)

Answer (score 1):

If I was the evaluator, I would ask questions like,

1) What is the research/business problem? 
Suggestion: Begin the report by clearly specifying the question

2) What are the existing solutions to solve the problem? 
Suggestion: Add a brief literature review on existing solutions for similar problems and their results preferably in a tabular format.

3) Briefly elaborate on the descriptive and multivariate properties of the data.
Suggestion: Add descriptive and inferential statistics on the data including some preliminary hypothesis that can be derived from the variable correlations.

4) Why did you choose this particular approach to solve the problem? 
Suggestion: Give credible justification backed up by quantitative hypothetical example solutions, that are in favour of the proposed approach.

5) If it's a classification task, I would ask a question like, "What is the baseline accuracy of the model?" And if its a clustering task, "What is the baseline for cluster purity?"
Suggestion: Find this accuracy from the target variable distribution.

Finally, you need to understand, why such an open-ended question is asked. There can be two possibilities;

(a) The company is new with reference to data science and is unsure of what they are looking for, meaning, they do not have either the required expertise to evaluate the candidate skills or they are simply unsure of what is their requirement. If this is the case, then it's imperative that the report is as simple and detailed as possible. Stay away from throwing jargon.

OR

(b) the company is experienced in data science and this is a filtering test. To filter out the self-proclaimed data scientist nincompoops, who think chaining some ready-made solution steps (*like preprocessing, dimensionality reduction, modelling*) solves a problem. The underlying idea is to figure out the analytical capabilities of a candidate.

Therefore, write the report wisely and ensure nothing is falsified.

Best of luck.

Comment: For part 5) Once I have the target variable variance, how would I use this throughout the training of my model? Should I compare the overall variance with the predicted variance and make an inference from that?

Comment: What is your understanding of data distribution? What do you think are the similarities and differences between variance and distribution?